# how to pass parameters to follow redirects in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I'm writing performance test.

In step #1 I'm visiting url: https://example.com/oauth/authorize

Since i have selected follow-redirect, it redirects to second url - https://example.authenticate.com/login

Now when the redirect happens i need to pass the username and password in-order to get authenticate and get bearer token from the result of the second url

In my JMeter script how can i pass the parameter when redirect happens?

Could you please tell me how it can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to "pass" the parameters you will need to create another [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to "enter" the credentials.

The redirect URL can be extracted from the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) header using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)

[image]

and once you have it you can use it in the 2nd HTTP Request sampler in form of a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri. Will try and let you know

Comment: Then in the first request shall i uncheck follow-redirect option?